# Overflow hidden in horizontal menu

Tags: css, overflow, css-float

During creating horizontal menu in CSS why there is used overflow: hidden to make this menu visible?

```
type here
```

I Would like to know why should we use overflow:hidden same as in example below:

[www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` have the style

```
float: left;
```

When an element is given any float styles, they are no longer in the document's normal flow. When you set overflow as hidden, you are creating a [block formatting context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context#) This contains all the floated elements, preventing the container from collapsing.

If you remove the `overflow:hidden` style, you'll see that the other `<li>` elements are gone until you hover over them.
By using `overflow:hidden`, you make sure that the parent container expands to contain its floated children.
Removing the style means that the parent container (`<ul>`) does not contain the floated children anymore, due to which they become invisible. Hovering over them just triggers the `:hover` styles.